# CircleCI gives "invalid user credentials" error while password is correct

Tags: ios, circleci, fastlane

I am using **Fastlane-Pilot** to upload builds to ***iTunesConnect***.

I add required **Fastlane** environment variables:

1. ***FASTLANE_PASSWORD***
2. ***PILOT_USERNAME***

to **CircleCI**'s ***Environment Variables*** (*https://circleci.com/gh/:your-name/edit#env-vars*).

However **Pilot** command fails with ***"Invalid user credentials"*** error.

And when I use the same password in my local machine, it **succeeds**.

Answer (score 0):

I added a line to my `circle.yml` to debug my environment variables as they are not available even during SSH session:

```
echo ${ENV_VAR_NAME}
```

and I saw that **CircleCI** didn't take all of the password that I put into *Environment Variables* through their UI. My password had several special symbols and **CircleCI** couldn't escape them correctly.

I hope they will fix that in the future but for now, you shouldn't use that kind of passwords with **CircleCI**